# LINQ inheritance query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, hierarchy

I'm supporting a system that has a hierarchy of groups that fall under an top level entity. Conceptually it looks like this:

```
id | Group      | parent
-------------------------
10 | Enterprise | N/A
20 | Partner A  | 10
21 | Partner B  | 10
29 | Business Q | 21
```

The actual group table looks like this:

```
int | GroupID
int | BusinessID (nullable)
int | PartnerID (nullable)
```

So the data looks like this:

```
GrpID | PtnrID | BzID  | Name
------------------------------------
10    | null   | null  | Enterprise
20    | 10     | null  | Partner A
21    | 10     | null  | Partner B
29    | 10     | 21    | Business Q
```

Instead of a group referring to a parent group, groups store partnerid and businessid which are nullable and point to another groups's GroupID.

Group-specific settings can be stored at any level. Enterprise defines the default value, but partner and business entities can override. Ex:

```
10 | color | red
20 | color | blue
29 | color | green
```

this would result in the following settings

```
Enterprise | red
Partner A  | blue
Partner B  | red
Business   | green
```

I'm trying to write a linq query that gets the setting for a given group, but am having trouble

```
from set in GroupSettings
from grp in Groups
where set.setting=="color" && grp.GroupID==29 && 
(
set.GroupID==grp.BusinessID || set.GroupID==grp.PartnerID
)
select set
```

this returns both the definition for Enterprise and the overridden value for the business

```
10 | red
29 | green
```

Is there a syntax that I can use that will give me (for lack of a better term) exclusive or functionality in my where clause that only falls through to the next or statement if the current one isn't met? My goal is to only return the relevant row - `29 | green` in this case.

Comment: I updated my post with more information. I was trying to keep the question as trimmed down as possible...

Comment: I have represented the data in tabular format. It may look a little weird because it's a partial representation of the actual system

Answer (score 1):

This Linq query does produce the correct output for the situation in your question. I basically have three left outer joins between group and its own setting, its business setting and its partner setting. This gives a result with 3 values. The projection selects the first non-null value.

```
var r = from grp in Groups
        join da in GroupSettings on grp.GroupID equals da.GroupID into ga // direct 
        join db in GroupSettings on grp.BzId equals db.GroupID into gb // Busisness
        join dc in GroupSettings on grp.PartnerId equals dc.GroupID into gc // Partner
        from gar in ga.DefaultIfEmpty()
        from gbr in gb.DefaultIfEmpty()
        from gcr in gc.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where grp.GroupID == 29
        select new { setting = gar ?? gbr ?? gcr };  // null coalesce
```

Comment: Props given for a solution. Unfortunately, when I try this with Linq-to-SQL it performs joins and returns a larger result set than the singular value I'm seeking.

Comment: I was afraid that could happen...can you add sample data to your question that would render a wrong result? I'll try to come up with a fix.